proper surjection of compact Kahlers implies injection on rational Hodge structures
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact Kahler manifolds, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper surjective morphism. Why is
$$
f^*: H^i(Y; \mathbb{Q}) \to H^i(X; \mathbb{Q})
$$
an injection on Hodge structures?

There's a proof of this in Voisin's Hodge theory book that uses Hodge theory, but I think this might be simpler.
Since $f : X \to Y$ is surjective the pullback $f^*$ is not the zero morphism. Since our manifolds are smooth the projection formula
$$
f_*(u \cup f^*v) = f_* u \cup v
$$
holds, where $u \in H^*(X,\mathbb C)$ and $v \in H^*(Y, \mathbb C)$. Since $X$ is Kähler there is a Kähler class $\omega$ on it. Putting $k = \dim X - \dim Y$ we then have
$$
f_*(\omega^k \cup f^*v) = f_* \omega^k \cup v
$$
for any class $v \in H^*(Y, \mathbb C)$.
Now $f_* \omega^k$ is a degree-zero class, that is a complex number, and it is not zero as we can check by picking a fiber $X_y = f^{-1}(y)$ that is smooth and integrating the $k$-th power of a Kähler metric in $\omega$ over it. If $f^*v = 0$ we then have $f_* \omega^k \, v = 0$ and thus $v = 0$.
This relies on us having Kähler manifolds because we need to be able to find a class on $X$ whose integral over the fibers of $f$ is nonzero, and the Kähler metrics give those classes. This doesn't work on non-Kähler manifolds: Consider the Hopf surface $S$ and recall that it has a surjective fibration $f : S \to \mathbb P^1$ whose fibers are elliptic curves. Famously we have $H^2(S,\mathbb C) = 0$ so $f^* : H^2(\mathbb P^1, \mathbb C) \to H^2(S, \mathbb C)$ is not injective.
